# Internet Archive dump of Stack Exchange access restricted

Tags: support, data-dump

The [data dump on the Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) says that signing in is required to access the files; however, even after signing in to the site, I only have access to 5 files (mostly metadata files), while the rest are marked as unavailable for download. What's the reason for this?

In addition, the torrent file says unavailable for download, but I was able to download it by copy and pasting its address in the browser, while another file (e.g., the Posts file for Stack Overflow) simply gives a "403 forbidden" error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATE**:
We have received confirmation that archive.org has fixed the issue with access to the data dump.

---

We have not intentionally placed any kind of restrictions on the data dump at archive.org.  We have contacted them to see if there was some kind of issue that forced them to require login.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not going to mark this as the answer yet, waiting for you to post what they say in response to you (so that I could mark that one as the answer).

Comment: To be clear, it's not *just* that it requires login (that seems reasonable to be honest). That started over a month ago, but users could still actually download the files while logged in. Now it seems that all but a few info files are just plain inaccessible, even while logged in. There's no obvious route to retrieving them.

Comment: Understood @animuson we have contacted archive.org

Comment: Trying to DL the latest torrent and it seems to work/ directly off of the IA site - and it is pulling it from web seeds. Its about 60% done but no issues otherwise.  So.. looks like I can confirm it works?